# Splitting a quotation

Tags: sentence-construction, quotations

*[Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/montreal-institute-going-open-accelerate-science)* magazine

> - Guy Rouleau, the director of McGill University’s Montreal Neurological Institute (MNI) and Hospital in Canada, is frustrated with how slowly neuroscience research translates into treatments. **“We’re doing a really shitty job,” he says. “It’s not because we’re not trying; it has to do with the complexity of the problem.”**

I have some questions related to quotation marks over the bald line.

1) Why writers, sometimes, separate the quoted words into two parts?. Why isn’t it like:

> - “We’re doing a really shitty job. It’s not because we’re not trying; it has to do with the complexity of the problem,” he says.

2) Even if the writer separated them, why didn’t he put after the second part  “‘he added after a while,’ or ‘he added’”or any phrase that define the second part of the quotation marks.

> - “We’re doing a really shitty job,” **he says**. “It’s not because we’re not trying; it has to do with the complexity of the problem,” **he added after while.**/ he added.

3)  And the third and last question is: would it matter if the part of speech “he added, he says” preceded or came after quotation marks, like:

> He says, “————-“
>
> “————,” he says

---

[source could help to understand paragraph construction](http://learn.lexiconic.net/writingdialogue.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is purely a stylistic choice, but it is quite common to see articles written with the construction: "A quote," he said. "And now some more quotes."

Beginning with the quote is good story-telling since it brings you into that person's point of view immediately, but then inserting the **he said** after the very first sentence helps to orient the reader and let them know exactly who is speaking.  If you put the **he said** all the way at the end, there's a chance that the reader might be confused about who is speaking and find themselves compelled to re-read the entire passage after they finally figure it out.

Finally, the reason you don't need a **he added** at the end is that there is a rule in English that if you change speakers, you must start a new paragraph.  If the paragraph is continuing, then the reader knows that the same person is continuing to speak, so it's unnecessary to re-identify the speaker.

---

Edited to add:

I should note that English speakers are *very* familiar with this quoting pattern and we get used to hearing it from a very young age.  Here's an example from Beatrix Potter's ["The Tale of Peter Rabbit"](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/148/peter-rabbit-and-other-stories/4923/the-tale-of-peter-rabbit/) (which was the book I made my parents read me over and over again when I was about three years old):

> “Now, my dears,” said old Mrs. Rabbit one morning, “you may go into the fields or down the lane, but don’t go into Mr. McGregor’s garden: your Father had an accident there; he was put in a pie by Mrs. McGregor.”

Comment: I didn’t know the point that if the speaker changed, Then we should start a new paragraph. Thank you.

Comment: http://learn.lexiconic.net/writingdialogue.htm I just saw it here, the last point you mentioned.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo - Yes, that's a very strict rule in English. Also I've added an example of this quoting pattern from children's literature.